# To classify finite p group with special property II

Tags: group-theory

I need your help in following question. I apologies for asking similar type questions. I would appreciate any help. I am sorry for the inconvenience.

I wish to classify $p$ group $G$ ($p$ prime) of order $p^4$ and $p^5$ such that
whenever $H$ is a non normal subgroup of order $p$, $G$ is the semidirect
product of $H$ and a subgroup $K$ with $K$ isomorphic to the quotient $G/L$
where $L$ is any normal subgroup of order $p$.

Can we classify finite $p$ group with this property.

Thanks in advance.

vipul kakkar

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have one single example of such a group? There are several things that can be said about such $\,G\;$ : it isn't abelian, $\,|Z(G)|=p\;\;\text{or}\;\;p^2\;$ ...yet the characterization you want looks pretty specific.

Comment: @ DonAntonio yes, if $G \cong C_p \ltimes (C_p \times C_p)$, then it satifies the hypothesis.

Comment: Your example has order $\;p^3\;$ . You asked about groups of order $\;p^4\;,\;p^5\;$ ...

Comment: @ DonAntonio Yes, for groups of order $p^4$ and $p^5$ I could not find example. Without using classification I need simple argument whether there exists a group with such property.